# Simple function calling doesn't work in Robot Framework

Tags: python, function, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm new to Robot FW and I'm in the learning stage. In order to try calling external libraries, I made a very simple function and saved in `tryingLibrary.py` file. The content:

```
def myAdding(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return z
```

Then I worte the following RF test

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Suite description
Library          tryingLibrary.py

*** Variables ***
${x}

*** Test Cases ***
TestTest
    ${x}=  myAdding     30      26
```

However, when I check the log file, I find `${x} = 3026`. I mean I'm expecting of course `56` not `3026`

*So where might be the problem?*

Comment: The parameters add as strings `"30"+"26"="3026"`

Comment: Try `z = int(x) + int(y)` in the `def myAdding(x, y):`
Robot f/w by default takes Unicode String as argument. You will have to explicitly convert it to `int` or the type you may want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to see this [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-types)

The doc clearly states that Argument type is Unicode String. There are two ways to implement  your desired behavior

1. Convert it in the python function like this

   ```
   def myAdding(x, y):
        z = int(x) + int(y)
        return z
   ```
2. Use it as follows, here is [doc](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables)

   ```
    *** Test Cases ***
    TestTest
         ${x}=  myAdding     ${30}      ${26}
   ```